# Cant get prices using checkboxes on IE and Safari. Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Need some help. This function runs fine on chrome. But it doesn't work on IE and safari. What am i doing wrong here?

```
function calculatePrice(){
var parts = [];
jQuery('li.parts li input').each(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")){
    parts.push(this.value);
  }
});

var price = 0.00;

  for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
  jQuery('.price-list li').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).find('.partname').text() === parts[i]){
      price = parseFloat(price) + parseFloat(jQuery(this).find('.partprice').text().replace('£ ', ''));
      price = price.toFixed(2);
    }
  });



}
price = 'Total: £ ' + price;
jQuery('.total-price span').html(price);
```

}

Comment: Please share your HTML code as well, otherwise we can't tell what's going on.

Comment: Actually this code is used in word press. I used it in gravity forms plugin so that when we click a check box it will get a value from the custom post UI form and will add the value to the total section.